# Angular 5 - Component selector tag with properties to manipulate HTML elements

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

I would like to ask you, how can I achieve this:

I have a component (lets name it FeatureComponent) with some box and inside this box three buttons. In another component (MainComponent) I'm using my FeatureComponent by selector tag . Now what I would like to do is to use selector tag from FeatureComponent like that:

```
<featurecomponent buttonOne="invisible" buttonTwo="disabled"></featurecomponent>
```

I've read about @Input & @Output and about directives, but I'm not sure if it's the right way.

Could someone advise me what I should use to achieve my goal?

EDIT:

Featurecomponent:

```
div class="group-radio-buttons">
<input type="radio"
      value="1"
      name="qaz"checked><small> buttonOne</small></div>
<input type="radio"
      value="2"
      name="qaz"><small> buttonTwo</small></div>
<input type="radio"
      value="3"
      name="qaz"><small> buttonThree</small></div>
</div>
```

And what I would like to achieve is to use this component in many other components but with possibility to manage this radio buttons like:

AnotherComponent:

```
<featurecomponent buttonOne="invisible" buttonTwo="disabled"></featurecomponent>
```

AnotherComponent2:

```
<featurecomponent buttonTwo="disabled"></featurecomponent>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you try to accomplish. If you add `@Input() buttonOne:string;` to your components class you can access the value using `ngOnInit() { console.log(this.buttonOne); }` The input value won't be available in the constructor which is executed before `ngOnInit`. http://angular.io has a lot of great tutorials

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I've edited my post to make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<featurecomponent buttonOne="invisible" buttonTwo="disabled"></featurecomponent>
```

Inputs allow to pass values to a component

```
class FeatureComponent {
  @Input() buttonOne:string;
  @Input() buttonTwo:string;
  @Input() buttonThree:string;
}
```

You can use view bindings to use the input values in the components template

```
<div class="group-radio-buttons">
<input type="radio"
      [attr.disabled]="buttonOne === 'disabled' ? true : null"
      [hidden]="buttonOne === 'invisible'
      value="1"
      name="qaz"checked><small> buttonOne</small></div>
<input type="radio"
      [attr.disabled]="buttonTwo === 'disabled' ? true : null"
      [hidden]="buttonTwo === 'invisible'
      value="2"
      name="qaz"><small> buttonTwo</small></div>
<input type="radio"
      [attr.disabled]="buttonThree === 'disabled' ? true : null"
      [hidden]="buttonThree === 'invisible'
      value="3"
      name="qaz"><small> buttonThree</small></div>
</div>
```

Disabled is a special attribute that has an effect no matter what the value is, this is why we use the for where we pass `true` or `null` because Angular completely removes an attribute if the value is `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Working perfectly.:)

Comment: Glad to hear. .